# Socket.io tutorial won't send message to console

Tags: html, node.js, sockets

Index.js:

```
ar app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');       
    });
});



http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    body {font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
    form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
    form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
    form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px;
        #messages {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding:0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background:#eee; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;

    });
    </script>

    <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

All i get in my terminal screen is 'a user connected' or 'a user disconnected' every time i type a message in my localhost. does anybody know where am i failing? those are my two node indexes files that i use in order to make the app work.
it seems that my send button is refreshing the page every time i press it, making the 'a client connected' message trigger.

Comment: It sounds like your form is submitting and thus reloading the page.

Comment: Every time i press send, it does exactly that!

Comment: A quick and dirty solution will be delete the <form> and </form>, aand assign a listener to onClick event of button pointing to a function to do the socket.emit(...)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to prevent the form default function.

```
var socket = io();

$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});

$('form').submit(function(){
   socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
   $('#m').val('');
   return false;
});
```